Estimating an integral of the Green function in the plane
Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded, simply connected domain, $z_{0}\in{\Omega}$ and for any $z\in{\Omega}$, $d_{z}:=\text{dist}(z,\partial{\Omega})$. I am interested in understanding the behavior of integrals of the form:
$$
\int_{\Omega}d_{z}^{-\beta}G_{\Omega}(z,z_{0})dA(z)
$$
where "$dA(z)$" is integration with respect to area on $\Omega$, and $\beta\in{(0,1/2)}$. If $\beta=0$, by interpreting this integral probabilistically as:
$$
\int_{\Omega}G_{\Omega}(z,z_{0})dA(z)=\mathbb{E}^{z_{0}}T_{\partial{\Omega}}
$$
where $T_{\partial{\Omega}}$ is the hitting time of $\partial{\Omega}$ by a planar Brownian motion, I can show that:
$$
\int_{\Omega}G_{\Omega}(z,z_{0})dA(z)\lesssim{d_{z_{0}}^{1/2}\text{diam}(\Omega)^{3/2}}
$$
However, without a probabilistic interpretation, I'm not sure what to do when $\beta\in{(0,1/2)}$. In particular, what I'm looking for is a quantitative upper bound for this integral that is strong enough to show that:
$$
\int_{\Omega}d_{z}^{-\beta}G_{\Omega}(z,z_{0})dA(z)\rightarrow{0} \hspace{5pt}\text{as $z_{0}\rightarrow{\partial{\Omega}}$}
$$

I undestand that the integral gives the solution of $\Delta u=d^{-\beta}$ with "Dirichlet boundary conditions". Is this correct?

Yes, that's correct.

The function $d^{-\beta}$ belongs to $L^2 (\Omega)$ and then $u \in H^2 \cap H^1_0$. By Sobolev embedding $\nabla u \in L^q$ for every $q<\infty$ and then (Sobolev again) $u$ is Holder continuous. Then $u=0$ at the boundary in a classical sense. If you use a suitable $p>2$ (so that $d^{-\beta} \in L^p$), then Sobolev embedding again gives $u \in C^1$ up to the boundary and then an estimate with the first power $d$. The constants however are not explicit and depend on the regularity of $\Omega$. However I obtain d and not $\sqrt{d}$ also for $\beta=0$, uinless I mixed some exponent.
